# Chrome can not visit localhost

Tags: google-chrome, nginx

I deployed my html by nginx on localhost with success last night, but when I get up this morning, I find the html failed to visit on Chrome but it work on Safari.

What Chrome send me is "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

My file `hosts` is display below which is no-problem I think.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Later, I replace current `nginx.conf` to original `nginx.conf` and I got the same result.

Thanks in advance.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root html;
            index index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }
    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include server/*;
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant nginx config files. P.S Do you have caching enabled?

Comment: @KeenanLawrence I finally find the reason which is that I'm using the proxy server, so I can't visit localhost.
But, what do you mean about caching enabled?

Comment: I see, 'm glad you got it working. On the topic of caching: If you implement caching in Nginx, and the user which nginx runs as doesn't have access to your caching folder, it returns an empty response.

Comment: Get it! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the reason which is that I'm using the proxy service, so I can't visit localhost.